# return statement binding rvalue reference to an lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I've been educated from several sources that in C++11 the return value of a function can be move-constructed from a return statement consisting of a named local variable.  For example:

```
class A {};

A f() {
    A a;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    f();
}
```

That is, in C++11, the prvalue temporary designated by the function call expression `f()` is move-constructed from the function's local variable `a`, instead of copy-constructed as in C++03.  Of course, this is all semantically speaking, before any level of optimization is taken, copy elision, NRVO, etc.

My question is, the argument of `A`'s move constructor is of type `A&&`, which can only bind to a prvalue or xvalue, right?  So which specific rule of exception allow its binding to the lvalue `a` here?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you stepped into this code?  I doubt that it does what you think its doing. For one you are not capturing the return value of f().

Comment: @Dan: Yes, I tried and it is the move constructor that is getting called, not the copy constructor.  You can try yourself by explicitly defining a public copy constructor and a private move constructor.  It will fail to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> which specific rule of exception allow its binding to the lvalue a here?

That's `12.8[class.copy]/32`

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

Comment: Thanks for this excerpt from the standard.  This seems to be the answer to my question.  Anyway, I don't fully understand the wording "`would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter`".  What does that mean?  Would you be so kind to elaborate a little bit on that?  Thanks again.

Comment: @goodbyeera that just refers to the criteria for copy elision that this paragraph refers to, which exclude function parameters. `A f(A a) { return a; }` does not allow copy elision, but performs a move.

Comment: @Cubbi But why `wasn't` the copy elision allowed in the past (C++11)? Note that the sentence "`would not be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter`" does not exist in C++14, C++17 and C++20.